Is copying a question from Reddit allowed here?
There's a question on a legal advice subreddit hat looks interesting but is getting very little attention.
What are the rules/ettiquette of reposting it here?

It would be best to just identify for yourself what aspect of the problem you are interested in learning about and then ask a focused question about what the law is.
That would avoid the things that make many legaladvice Reddit posts poor fits for this platform.
How to ask a good question?
